# How can I send data to a Unity3D game through SignalR on HTML5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, unity-game-engine, signalr

I followed the tutorial from the German Blog [here](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fcodefest.at%2Fpost%2F2014%2F09%2F11%2FSignalR-und-Unity-in-euren-Multiplayer-Indie-Games.aspx).

Afterwards I created a script that sends prints out the coordinates of the HTML5 hand when clicked on the screen. I would like to send those coordinates to the Unity Game using the provided Server and Clients.

While I am not moving forward with this particular example, I will be looking at other examples with SignalR, and will take other Networking suggestions that will allow unity and webplayer to have connection.

**Unity Code: (sends data) 
Playercontrollers.cs(1/2)**

```
using UnityEngine; 

public class Playercontrollers : MonoBehaviour { 

    public Camera cam; 
    private float maxWidth; 
    private float maxHeight; 

    bool isHandOpen = true; 
    public Sprite clickedSprite; 
    private Sprite standardSprite; 

    private SignalRUnityController _signalr; 

    void Start() 
    { 
        if (cam == null) 
            cam = Camera.main;

       _signalr = GameObject.Find("SignalRObject").GetComponent<SignalRUnityController>();

        var corner = new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0f); 
        var targetWidth = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(corner); 
        float playerWidth = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.x; 
        float playerHeight = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.y; 
        maxWidth = targetWidth.x - playerWidth; 
        maxHeight = targetWidth.y - playerHeight; 

        standardSprite = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite; 

    } 
    void FixedUpdate() 
    { 
        var currentPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); 
        float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth); 
        float targetHeight = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.y, -maxHeight, maxHeight); 
        var newPosition = new Vector3(targetWidth, targetHeight, 0f); 
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(newPosition); 

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        { 
            isHandOpen = false; 
            MouseDown(); 
        } 
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
        { 
            isHandOpen = true; 
            MouseUp(); 
        } 

        var worldCoordinates = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(newPosition);
        var json = "{"+string.Format("\"x\": \"{0}\", \"y\": \"{1}\", \"handOpen\": \"{2}\"", worldCoordinates.x, worldCoordinates.y, isHandOpen) +"}";
        //var json = "{\"x:791, y:10,handOpen: True\"}";
        Debug.Log(json);
        _signalr.Send("Position", json); 

    } 

    private void MouseDown() 
    { 
        Debug.Log("MouseDown"); 
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = clickedSprite; 

    } 

    private void MouseUp() 
    { 
        Debug.Log("MouseUp"); 
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = standardSprite; 
    } 
    public static void Receive()
    {
        Debug.Log("Change position from controller");
        //var newPosition = new Vector3(450, 175, 0f);
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(newPosition);

    }

}
```

**SignalRUnityController.cs** (2/2)

```
using SignalR.Client._20.Hubs;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SignalRUnityController : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool useSignalR = true;
    public string signalRUrl = "http://localhost:50283/";

    private HubConnection _hubConnection = null;
    private IHubProxy _hubProxy;
    private IHubProxy _hubProxyReceive;
    private Subscription _subscription;
    public Playercontrollers player;



    //start connection to the outer web page
    void Start () {

        if (useSignalR)
            StartSignalR();
    }

    void StartSignalR()
    {
        if (_hubConnection == null)
        {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnection(signalRUrl);

            _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateProxy("signalRHub");
            _subscription = _hubProxy.Subscribe("broadcastMessage");
            _subscription.Data += AudioDataLoadState =>
            {
                Debug.Log("signalR called us back");
                Playercontrollers.Receive();

            };
            _hubConnection.Start();

        }
        else
            Debug.Log("SignalR already connected...");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Send single message of direction over broadcast
    /// </summary>
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Send(string method, string message){
        if (!useSignalR)
            return;

        var json = "{" + string.Format("\"action\": \"{0}\", \"value\": {1}", method, message) + "}";
        _hubProxy.Invoke("Send", "UnityClient", json);

    }
    public void Receive(string method, string message)
    {
       // if (!useSignalR)
          //  return;

        //_hubProxyReceive.Subscribe("Receive", "UnityClient");

    }

}
```

**Visual Studio Project, (index and hubs)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Unity to webPlayer Sample </title>

    <Style> 
      body {
        background: url(images/game-background.png);
        /*background-size54321:*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }

      #player {

        position: absolute;

        top: 30px;

        left: 30px;

      }
      #contentContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

      </Style>

</head>


<body>
    <div id="contentContainer">
        <img id="player" src="images/OpenHand.png" />
        </div>


        <div id="infoContainer">

            <label id="message"></label>

        </div>       
        <div id="transportContainer">

            <label id="connected"></label>

        </div>

        <!---Script references. -->
        <!--Reference the jQuery Library54321. -->

        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

        <!--Reference the SignalR library54321. -->

        <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->

        <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

        <!--Add script to update the page and receive messages.-->
    <script src="//www.kirupa.com/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var theThing = document.querySelector("#player");
            var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");

            container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

            function getClickPosition(e) {
                var parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
                var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
                var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);

                theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
                theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
                console.log(xPosition + " " + yPosition);
            }

            // Helper function to get an element's exact position
            function getPosition(el) {
                var xPos = 0;
                var yPos = 0;

                while (el) {
                    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
                        // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
                        var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                        var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

                        xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
                        yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
                    } else {
                        // for all other non-BODY elements
                        xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
                        yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
                    }

                    el = el.offsetParent;
                }
                return {
                    x: xPos,
                    y: yPos
                };
            }
            $(function () {
                var hub = $.connection.SignalRHub;
                var echo = $.connection.echo;

                echo.client.greetings = function (message) {
                    $('#message').html(message);

                };

                var started = hub.start();

                started.done(function () {
                    echo.server.say("hello! New User 5671 joined");
                });

            });

            $(function () {
                //$('#message').text('connected');

                //  Declare a proxy to reference the hub.

                var signalrHub = $.connection.signalRHub;





                //Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.

                signalrHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                    console.log(message);
                    var messageobj = JSON.parse(message);



                    if (messageobj.action == 'Position') {
                        console.log("Position + Position");

                        $('#player').css('left', messageobj.value.x + 'px');// update the x value
                        $('#player').css('top', 500 - $('#message').height() - messageobj.value.y + 'px');// update the x value
                        $('#message').text('x:' + messageobj.value.x + "px, y:" + messageobj.value.y + 'px');
                        if (messageobj.value.handOpen == 'True')
                            $('#player').attr('src', 'Images/OpenHand.png');
                        else
                            $('#player').attr('src', 'Images/ClosedHand.png');
                    }
                };

                var started = signalrHub.start({
                    transport: [
                    'webSockets',
                    'longPolling',
                    'serverSentEvents',
                    'foreverFrame'
                    ]

                });

                //start the connection to the server to display on the webpage
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#message').text('connected');
                    $('#connected').text('connected, transport: ' + signalrHub.transport.name);
                    console.log('connected, transport: ' + signalrHub.transport.name)
                });


                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#contentContainer').click(function () {
                        console.log("Clicked");
                        //Call the Send method on the hub. 
                        //chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                        //$('#message').val('').focus();
                    });
                });

            });

        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

**SIgnalRHub(2/3)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;            //include this to add hub names ["echo"]

namespace SignalRUnityWeb

{
    /// <summary name="SignalRHub">Name of the c# file</summary>
    [HubName("hub") ]
    public class signalRHub : Hub
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The purpose of receive if for the Unity to have a function called receive that receives data from the web page
        /// </summary>    
        /// <param name="name">name of the connection</param>
        /// <param name="message">single message to be sent through network</param>
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            //Call the broadcastMessage method to update the clients.

            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRUnityWeb.Startup))]

namespace SignalRUnityWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the solution part:

1. Do I have to add another signalHub?
2. Should I change Still use broadcast to all?
3. Which file do I change for UNity? Should I create another .cs file called Listener.cs?
4. Which file do I change for the HTML5 index to be correct?
5. What is the name of the function(receive?)
6. Will the solution scale or is it a patch?

Comment: Any news? have you got that to work?

Comment: SignalR works fine, but getting it to work with multitouch has too many parameters, I switched to TUIO using a python Webstream connecting locally to a Java TUIO application using IDEA Pycharm and Java